# Error correction in names

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, error-correction

I am trying to device an algorithm that performs error correction in names. My approach is having a database with the correct names, compute edit distance between each of them and the name entered and then suggest the 5 or 10 closest.

This task is significantly different from standard error correction in words as some of the names might be replaced by initials. For instance "Jonathan Smith" and "J. Smith" are actually quite close and could easily be considered the same name, so the edit distance should be really small if not 0. Another challenge is that some names might be written differently while sounding the same. For instance `Shnaider` and `Schneider` are versions of the same name written by people with different locales(there are better examples for that I guess). And another case - just imagine all the possible errors in writing `Jawaharlal Nehru` most of which have nothing to do with the real name. Again probably most of them will be similar phonetically.

Obviously Lucene's error correction algorithm will not help me here as it does not handle the above cases.

So my question is: do you know any library capable of doing error correction in names? Can you propose some algorithm for handling the cases mentioned above?

I am interested in libraries in c++ or java. As for algorithm proposals any language or pseudo code will do.

Comment: I see 2 possible approaches here: 1. Have a dictionary of synonyms and include it when calculating the distance. 2. Employ some AI module with the logic you described.

Comment: I believe only option 2 is possible for me as I have millions of names, different locales, different synonyms. The problem here is **how** to implement the logic I describe specifically the phonetic similarity part. Also I wanted to make sure nothing similar is no already out there.

Comment: Be very careful doing this. I just finished a multi-week argument with UCSD, where I was a student for a few years ending in 2009. They were charging me for a returned check. It was only resolved when I finally got them to dig out the image of the check, rather than just looking at their records. The check was actually written by someone with the same first and last name, but with a middle initial. The accounting department had assumed it belonged on my account based on the name near-match. Even exact name matches are not much use for determining whether data is about the same person.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I intend to use the algorithm for error correction not for identification so I should be on the safe side here. Also I will offer the few highest ranked options not only a single one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For phonetic matching, see [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex).

I think modifying a Levenshtein distance algorithm to treat "abbreviate to an initial" and "expand from an initial" as single-distance edits ought to be straightforward, but the details are beyond me at the moment.

Comment: Soundex definitely is something I can make use of. Thank you for that :)

Answer (score 3):

You might also look at [Metaphone](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Metaphone.html).